# Any databases with this data?

Tags: data-request, medical, biology

Has anybody seen a medical data set with:

- clinical data (patient's age, gender, prior history, and stuff like that)
- biomarkers (blood pressure, blood oxygenation, etc.)
- genetic data (preferably gene expression or miRNA data)
- imaging data (not necessary, but preferred)
- and **most importantly** information about treatment and **how the patient changed as a result of the treatment**.

For example, I want to see a specific patient's gene expression data, then see that they went through "Radiation Therapy", then see the new gene expression levels afterwards.

What disease this is for or the completeness of the data doesn't concern me (i.e I'd be fine with having imaging data for just a couple of patients). I'm looking into applying some graph theory state-based algorithms to this data in order to create a model that determines which treatment to use for a specific patient.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at TCGA (https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcga/)? It seems to have genetic data, clinical data, and (if you use the extension TCIA) imaging data.

I'm not sure, however, that it has data about patient outcomes, and it certainly doesn't have genetic data from after treatments.

Comment: I already knew about TCGA but didn't know you could use TCIA to get imaging data for some patients! This seems like it would be useful, but I really need a dataset that gives me miRNA data after treatment.